# Identical Laravel API login requests result in 200/400 dependant on grant_type and oauth client details supplied by request or by PHP

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

I am currently working on dockerizing a web application that includes a MariaDB database, Laravel API, and React front end. I have dockerized it into three containers: database, API, and front end. I am encountering an odd issue with user login, oauth via laravel/passport.

Authentication is designed to work via "email/password" submission from the front end, which I am testing from the API swagger interface.

This all works as expected outside of docker. Inside docker, however, I have to explicitly add the client_id, client_secret, and grant_type to the request body to get a 200.

What is deeply confusing to me is that I can see the PHP, which automatically adds these fields to the body,

```php
    public function login($email, $password)
    {
        try {
            request()->request->add([
                'grant_type' => 'password',
                'client_id' => config('auth.passport_config.client_id'),
                'client_secret' => config('auth.passport_config.client_secret'),
                'username' => $email,
                'password' => $password,
                'scope'         => '',
            ]);
            $request = Request::create(config('auth.passport_config.server_url') . '/oauth/token', 'POST');
            $response = Route::dispatch($request);
            $errorCode = $response->getStatusCode();
            $auth_server_response = json_decode((string) $response->content(), true);
            if ($errorCode == '200') {
                return [
                    "response_body" => $auth_server_response,
                    "status" => 200
                ];
            } else {
                return [
                    "response_body" => [
                        'message' => 'Authentication has failed!',  // User credentials are invalid
                        'authentication_server_response' => $auth_server_response
                    ],
                    "status" => $errorCode
                ];
            }
        }
        catch (\Exception $e) {
            return [
                "response_body" => [
                    'message' => 'Authentication has failed!',  // User credentials are invalid
                ],
                "status" => 401
            ];
        }
    }
```

Indeed, I can see that the request bodies **are** identical and being delivered to the same address - yet one (grant_type and client details in request body) is consistently resulting in a 200, and the other one (grant_type and client details from php) a 400 Bad Request with an error message of

```
{
  "message": "Authentication has failed!",
  "authentication_server_response": {
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server.",
    "hint": "Check that all required parameters have been provided",
    "message": "The authorization grant type is not supported by the authorization server."
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the two requests side-by-side.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOXkR.jpg)

I am stuck on where I can even progress exploration. My naive assumption was that an identical request sent to an identical address should yield an identical result.